# Access front page node only by front page link

Tags: 7, redirection, nodes

I have a problem with front page node redirection. I have created a node which I want to be a front page (let's say it's path is `node/6`). I have also set "**Default front page**" path with path of my node. The problem is that my node is accessible by two links now:

- `http://example.com/`
- `http://example.com/node/6`

How can I make my node to be accessible only by front page link?

Comment: It'll always be available by two URLs, that's just how it works...are you worried about SEO and duplicate content?

Comment: @Clive, no worries about SEO. I just have read that there must be redirect, and was wondering why it's not working in my case. Link (comment #1): http://drupal.org/node/1192920#comment-4865090

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want http://example.com/node/6 to redirect to http://example.com/, I'd take a look at the global redirect module: http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect

Comment: hopefully, it should shortcut solution